# Not selecting duplicates from MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a DB structure like:

```
player1 | player2  | score
Prust   | Val      | 1
Dan     | Prust    | 10
Dan     | Prust    | 5
Prusel  | Prust    | 1
```

Each person has a link, such as `mySite.com/Prust`.

I'm building a search function on my site.

When someone enters for example "Pru" in the search input, the query should return 2 players, one for Prust and one for Prusel, so then I can show the links for these 2 players in my popup box. (For example displaying "We found 2 players similar to the inputted text: Prusel and Prust.")

And also, because I have the `OR` statement, I am not sure which of player1 or player2 column was successfully used to find the record in the DB.

Right now, my query looks like:

`SELECT * FROM games WHERE player1 LIKE 'pru' OR player2 LIKE 'pru'`;

This of course doesn't achieve what I want... And that's where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would raise questions about if you have modeled your data correctly, but I believe this query should suffice.

```
select distinct (player1)
from games
where player1 like 'pru%'
union
select distinct (player2)
from games
where player2 like 'pru%';
```

Comment: Hi, what about selecting the score as well?

Comment: I thought the requirements were to return the two players names? "We found 2 players similar to the inputted text: Prusel and Prust."

Comment: Actually I don't need the score in my case. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You also can use a GROUP BY keyword

```
    SELECT player1 
    FROM games
    WHERE player1 like 'pru%'
    GROUP BY player1 

    UNION 

    SELECT player2
    FROM games
    WHERE player2 like 'pru%';
    GROUP BY player2
```